# IIS URL Rewrite condition file exists using capture groups?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, conditional-statements, url-rewrite-module

Seems like this would be really easy but can't seem to find an example.

User types in the following URL:

> http://www.mysite.com/business/chelan/internet

I want it to go to:

> /business/internet_chelan.php

ONLY if the file exists there. Otherwise, go to:

> /business/internet.php

"Chelan" is a county in my area. If I want to create a specific page for that county, I could simply add "_chelan" to my file. Otherwise, it just goes to the general internet page.

So I use the following to grab URL parts:

> ^(business|residential)/([^/]+)/(.+)

and rewrite to:

> {R:1}/{R:3}_{R:2}.php

Works beautifully... but I want to have the condition:

> if {R:1}/{R:3}_{R:2}.php "Is a file" rewrite to {R:1}/{R:3}_{R:2}.php

But it seems like {R:} does not work in conditions??? Is this true or is there some other way I can write it? I've seen {C:1} and $1 but they don't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

*IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 using URL Rewrite module*